# CSS / HTML / JS not updating XAMPP (local development) - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, server-setup, xampp

I've tried to install Magento 2 locally using XAMPP. This works fine, except for the fact that when I alter my CSS, HTML, or JS, XAMPP won't get the updated files. It just takes the file I initially created with its content, but not the updated version.

I think this has something to do with caching of Apache itself?
I read something about disable cache using `.htaccess` (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_cache.html) but I can't figure out how to implement this.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Flushing cache doesn't work.
Deploy static content may work, but I don't want to do that every time I make one minor change in the CSS (when I worked remotely, I did not have to do that either)

The developer mode is enabled.

Comment: have you tried after cache flush and static content deploy commands?

Comment: Yep. I used to work remotely, which would not have me to constantly deploy the static content or flush the cache when I alter the css.  When I flush the cache working locally, it won't update.

Comment: For windows env. I will prefer to use Git bash.

Comment: @MR.RDNATH how is that related to my question?

Comment: you can use grunt for CSS and for JS you can use magento developer mode.

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with compiling or my code. My webserver won't simply use the updated files, even tho they are updated. I am in developer mode.

Comment: In win env, it create this type of issue for file generate.
As during deploy static files , it create folder and files dynamically.
In Early day's, i was using win env, so use git bash for deployment & permission.
It will help you to use linux env in win system.

Comment: @MR.RDNATH but how is my XAMPP server in any way related to using Git? Or I am missing your point

Comment: you are using command prompt for deployment or other cmd for M2.
Just download GIT bash for those work, not  command prompt.
It is just an shell interface to run linux cmd in windows env.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just working locally, try enabling developer mode. With the developer, mode enabled you won't need to redeploy the content all the time. You will need to flush the cache but if you are working on a decent machine with an SSD, you can also disable the cache through the admin.

You can enable developer mode in several ways but a quick way is just to edit the "app/etc/env.php" file. There should be a line that says "'MAGE_MODE'". By default I think it says:

```
'MAGE_MODE' => 'default',
```

it should be as simple as changing it to:

```
'MAGE_MODE' => 'developer',
```

and then flushing or disabling the cache. I really don't recommend disabling the cache unless you are working off of an SSD. It is unusably slow on a normal drive.

Comment: As you can see in my question, unfortunately I already have developer mode enabled and flushing the cache doesn't work. I think this may not be Magento 2 related so I will post my question on stack overflow